# Visual studio 2013 keeps crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So I have a machine which runs Windows 10 with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.
But everytime I start the program it crashes within 1 minute, even without even moving my mouse.

When it crashes it gives me the following error: An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe [6820]

I have noticed that the error started coming up after I connected to a Team Foundation Server, but I dont know if it has anything to do with the issue.

Furthermore, I am running a clean Windows install so that shouldn't be the problem either.

At this point I really don't know what to do, and I have my exams in two weeks, with which I need Visual Studio with Team Foundation Server.

Please help me with this, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is Visual Studio updated to the latest version?

Comment: Assuming update 5 is the latest version, yes.

Comment: Tried the obvious? Uninstalling VS and re-installing?

Comment: Yup a couple of times, even re-installed windows, and to make sure it wasn't a harddrive kind of issue, replaced that aswell.