# Visual Studio 2013 keeps crashing with error denev.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I have a machine which runs Windows 10 with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. But everytime I start the program it crashes within 1 minute, even without even moving my mouse.

When it crashes it gives me the following error: An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe [6820]

I have noticed that the error started coming up after I connected to a Team Foundation Server, but I dont know if it has anything to do with the issue.

Furthermore, I am running a clean Windows install so that shouldn't be the problem either.

At this point I really don't know what to do, and I have my exams in two weeks, with which I need Visual Studio with Team Foundation Server.

Please help me with this, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Can you debug the crashed devenv.exe with another debugger to determine what exception occurred?  I did it and got a System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: Some people at my work had this issue today too. Maybe file a support request with Microsoft?

Comment: Another culprit could be you video driver. Try running visual studio with the "/safemode" option. Then turn off hardware acceleration in the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you may need to repair your installation of the .Net framework.

To do this, please goto:

1. Control Panel >>> Programs >>> Programs and features >> Microsoft .Net Framework ClientProfile/Core >>> Select Repair >>> .Net Framework (.net version here)
2. Alternatively, you can use the setup verification tool to diagnose your .Net Framework here: [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool](http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog%7C_Tools/netfx%7C_setupverifier%7C_new.zip) or [Alternatively](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/netfx_setupverifier_new.zip). Also check the [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool User’s Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/)
3. If you do find problems with your .Net Framework, you can use the Repair Tool to fix it, it is designed to fix issues specifically concerning the .Net Framework as well as updates: [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

After repairing, restart your system and please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have also noticed your question was literally copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661914/visual-studio-2013-keeps-crashing, which was published on Jan 7 '16. Though the was no answer to the question, I don't think that is ethical here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. The answer is to install Update 5 for Visual Studio 2013:

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202013%20Update%205

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem at the office, seems like its a Microsoft issue.

here is a workaround:
https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/7a2uy3/workaround_visual_studio_is_crashing_for_me_today/